# C# socket error, unable to send as socket is not connected?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am trying to get to grips with sockets and it is proving a bit harder than I thought. I have googled this error and have tried to fix it myself by toying with my code but I do not understand what is not right here. The following code is giving me a socket exception with the error "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied." As you can see I am trying this on my local machine, the client simply connects and sends a string. Any tips or pointers would be nice!

*NOTE* I have read other similar questions here on Stack Overflow but have not managed to fix my program with the solutions!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Socket socket = null;
        private static Socket client = null;
        private static IPAddress ipAddress = null;
        private static int port = 1090;
        private static IPEndPoint endPoint = null;
        private static byte[] buffer;
        private static int socketRecv = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(GetLocalIPv4(NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet));
            endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
            buffer = new byte[1024];

            Console.WriteLine("\nVariables initialized...");

            socket.Bind(endPoint);
            socket.Listen(5);

            Console.WriteLine("\nSocket bound and listening...");

            client = socket.Accept();

            Console.WriteLine("\nSocket accepted connection...");
            //the program gets to here, then the exception is thrown

            while (true)
            {
                if (socketRecv == 0)
                {
                    socketRecv = socket.Receive(buffer);
                    continue;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nData wrote...\n");
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
            Console.Read();

        }

        public static string GetLocalIPv4(NetworkInterfaceType _type)
        {
            string output = "";
            foreach (NetworkInterface item in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (item.NetworkInterfaceType == _type && item.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in item.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            output = ip.Address.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to call client.Receive(), not socket.Receive(). Also the exact purpose of the while loop is not clear for me - in real world you'll read until the call to Receive() returns 0 (for blocking socket that would signal that the socket has been closed).

Comment: also what happens if you change `ProtocolType.Tcp` to `ProtocolType.Udp` will that work in regards to `SocketType.Stream` ?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I'm an idiot xD, thank you. As for the loop; it is a bit pointless but this is just me messing about with sockets to try learn how to use them, not really designed it well. All done now; if you post an answer with the same text I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: Socket's approach to "issue" a different socket when accepting a connection is confusing or any newcomer. Hope you deal with graceful shutdown, that's another quite complicated thing to do right (calling Close without Shutdown will cause unpleasant side effects).

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Yeah, it is a little confusing but I don't expect it to be easy ^.^ Thanks for the advice, I'll look into how to shut sockets down properly too. Now back to Google and tutorials! Thanks for the help.